# MySQL Prepare statement syntax

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement

I am having trouble getting my prepare statement to run in MySQL 5.6.14; here is the block of code in question:

```
SET @backupDate = DATE(NOW());
SET @renameTable = CONCAT('RENAME TABLE activeDirectoryData TO actDirBackup-', @backupDate);
PREPARE goRenameTable FROM @renameTable;
EXECUTE goRenameTable;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE goRenameTable;
```

The script stops at the prepare statement, with the following error:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '-2013-11-06' at line 1

Any idea what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name `actDirBackup-` with the value coming from `@backupDate` isn't a valid table name, you have to escape it, something like this:

```
SET @renameTable = CONCAT('RENAME TABLE activeDirectoryData TO `actDirBackup-',
                          @backupDate, '`');
```

Comment: Yes, that did the trick! What is the character you used to escape the name, and where is it referenced in the MySQL documentation?

Comment: @SillyGoof - It is two ` `, See [**Identifier Qualifiers**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html)